# Shared Config(at git) between SPring Boot Services

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-configuration

I am developing spring boot services.

So lets say I have 3 Services A, B, C with dev and prod profiles each. Now I am keeping the configuration for these services at GIT and using config server to fetch the configuration.

So when I run A service in prod mode, the config file A-prod.properties is getting used.

Now I want to keep some common configuration which will be used by all 3 Services say common-prod.properties. How should I do that?

I have tried this:

Config Server :

```
spring:
  cloud:
    config:
      server:
        git:
          uri: http://gitPaath/Configs.git
          username: <username>
          password: <pass>
          cloneOnStart: true
          searchPaths: "{common}"
```

My properties are file are in Git Repo in this order :

```
- A-prod.properties
- A-dev.properties
- B-prod.properties
- A-dev.properties
- C-prod.properties
- C-dev.properties
- common
   - common-prod.propeties
   - common-dev.properties
```

Comment: Are you able to resolve this issue, if yes please share the solution

Comment: The solution is the accpeted answer below. simple create application-<profile>.properties file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put all shared properties between services in `application-<profile>.properties` file.

In your case, make `application-prod.properties` and `application-dev.properties` files and put these file on root folder or any folder that is searchable by config server.

You can find more details in "Sharing Configuration With All Applications" section in [here](http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-config/1.3.1.RELEASE/).