# Shared Config Between SOME Spring Boot Services

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-boot-configuration

This question is similar to (but different in the aim): [Shared Config(at git) between SPring Boot Services](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45499251/shared-configat-git-between-spring-boot-services) so I will make use of the example the OP wrote there.

In my case I am using Spring Cloud Config Server with the Vault as backend, but for the sake of argument I will describe it as if it were in git. So imagine I have 4 Services: `A, B, C and D`.

And I have the following configs:

```
- A-prod.properties
- A-dev.properties
- B-prod.properties
- B-dev.properties
- C-prod.properties
- C-dev.properties
- D-prod.properties
- D-dev.properties
- application-prod.properties
- application-dev.properties
```

Now according to the [docs](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-config/2.0.2.RELEASE/single/spring-cloud-config.html#_sharing_configuration_with_all_applications) I will have one of the services, let's say `Service C` getting his properties from `C-(ENV).properties` as well as `application-(ENV).properties`. Similarly the same with the others, i.e. everyone gets their own file and everything on `application.properties`.

**My question is**:
Is it possible to have for example a "semi-global" shared properties, e.g. a file that `A and C` share some config and another that `B and D` share some config?

An usage example would be DB Connection Credentials, where two services make use of one set of credentials, and the others another one.

I have been trying to find infos about this and doing some tests, but nothing that got me anywhere...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, it's not possible to achieve what you want. The only way to share properties is by using the `application.properties(yml)` file which is merged to every other configuration file.

Comment: ok... thanks for explaining anyway! I guess we just have to get along and change the workflow to accommodate it